# Localizing ASP markup in webpart issue

Tags: web-part, localization, visual-web-part, aspx

In my web part I have an label, which I want to be localized:

```
<asp:Label ID="AppJSTNameLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:AppListWebPart,NoSelection%>" />
```

I have mapped `Resources` folder and created there files: `AppListWebPart.resx` and `AppListWebPart.pl-PL.resx`.

Both resource files contain NoSelection key with appropriate translations, but every time I deploy and test my web part, I'm getting:

```
Parser Error Message: The resource object with key 'NoSelection' was not found.
```

This drives me crazy. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding `resources` to mapped `Resource` folder you are placing resx files to `<hive>\xx\Resources\` folder and your web part cannot access them.

Proper place for this kind of resource is IIS application `App_GlobalResources` folder (`x:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<port>\App_GlobalResources\`).

Fore more info you can read [SharePoint Internals: Resources](http://tomblog.insomniacminds.com/2008/02/25/sharepoint-internals-resources/) (a bit old but it covers your issue).

If you are using 2010 with VS 2010 then you just add `Module` item to your project, delete all files included by default, put your resx inside it and use item properties on resx item  to set `Deployment Type : AppGlobalResource`

For 2007 you can use:
[SharePoint Resources, Types, Use and Deployment](http://www.mikhaildikov.com/2007/03/sharepoint-resources-types-use-and_2163.html)